# Data Metrix is not recognized by Android ML Kit

Tags: android, firebase, google-mlkit

I have the image of data matrix code with the dark background, I am not able to scan the code from the image . I am pasting the image here

[image]
[image]

This is my  code:

```
val barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(
        BarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
            .enableAllPotentialBarcodes()
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_128,Barcode.FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX)
            .build()
    )

imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(binding.previewView.display.rotation)
        .build()
```

Please let me know anybody can get the code out of the images. I tried lot of 3rd party app from playstore, but except CODE SCANNER (Using ZXING lib) none of the apps can scan this code. But this works in iOS.